# What file formats are supported for the Web Audio API convolution functions?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I've built simple convolution functionality into my site using the Web Audio API (javascript), which works when both the source file and the impulse response are .wav files, but the audio fails to output and returns no error when I use other formats.

I've looked through the Web Audio API Spec, and can't see a mention of file format specifics. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: see [audio format support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#Browser_compatibility) And I know nothing of convolution, but maybe it does not work on compressed audio formats such as mp3

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think you might be right, at least judging by the examples they give the impulse response always seems to be a .wav, even though it's not explicitly stated in the spec.

Comment: I've only ever gotten it to work with a stereo .wav.

Answer (score 1):

The create buffer file can be in any format which is supported by the audio element: mp3, wav, ogg.

I use wav file format for convolution effects.
Convolution effects are small so this did work for me in wav.

Most of my tracks are mp3. Beware of the sample rate.:-)

Comment: I'm trying it now, Edge has problems with `.ogg` files, saying the format is not supported. It works in Chrome without problems.